# How to shuffle from a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, random, sampling

Suppose that we have the following vector that could change within a loop but with fixed length:

```
V = c(8,15,16,7,3)
```

I need to shuffle in each iteration m compenents at uniform from `V`.  ( 1<=m<=5 & m is integer)

Then I will need to store those components in their respective positions at another vector `K` with the same length as `V`. The other positions will simply contain the value `0`.

For example: let j be the current iteration and let assume that `V` will not change. some possible results could be :

```
m=3
---------------------
//
j=1
V= c(8,15,16,7,3)
K= c(0,15,0,7,3)   # 3 numbers are shuffled //


//
j=2
V= c(8,15,16,7,3)
K= c(8,0,0,7,3)   # 3 numbers are shuffled
 //
.
.
.

j=4
V= c(8,15,16,7,3)
K= c(0,0,16,7,3)   # 3 numbers are shuffled
```

I wish my question and the desired output is clear.
Thank a you a lot for help!

Comment: i don't understand your description, it seems like you are randomly selecting m elements and replacing the others with 0--where is the shuffling? `replace(V, sample(5, 2), 0)`

Comment: Yes exactly , sorry that i complicated the question for you ! Thank you a lot for precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very rough solution, but it should answer your question.

```
# initialization of parameters
V = c(8, 15, 16, 7, 3)
m = 3    
n_iter = 10
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = n_iter, ncol = length(V))

# creation of matrix
set.seed(42)
for (j in 1:n_iter)
  mat[j,] <- replace(V, sample(5, 2), 0)
```

Output

```
 #       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #  [1,]    8   15    0    0    3
 #  [2,]    8    0   16    0    3
 #  [3,]    8   15    0    7    0
 #  [4,]    0   15   16    7    0
 #  [5,]    8   15    0    7    0
 #  [6,]    0   15   16    0    3
 #  [7,]    8   15   16    0    0
 #  [8,]    8    0   16    0    3
 #  [9,]    8   15    0    0    3
 # [10,]    8    0   16    7    0
```